# C# creating restaurant menu - blinking button with table number

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create restaurant menu with c# for college. Actually there's two applications (customer and waitress) and they are communicating via txt files. On customer side I have `toolStripStatusLabel` and it shows randomly selected table number(1 to 18). On waitress side i should have 18 buttons (tables) and when some dishes are ordered the certain table button should blink. Any ideas how i could implement it? On customer side i can send table number to txt file, but how to take it and use it on waitress side?

Comment: "Any ideas how i could implement it?"  We need to know how much you know or don't know.  For example, do you know how to read and write to text files?

Comment: I use StreamWriter file to write to file and this "File.ReadAllLines(fileSystemWatcher1.Path + "\\" + fileSystemWatcher1.Filter)" to read from file.

Comment: Ok, so show us some code and tell us exactly where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these can be solved with a Timer as an easy solve.

Button Blinking:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button1.BackColor == Color.Gray)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

You'll have to specify how fast you want the button to blink when you start the timer:

```
    timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(2000); //This is blinking every 2 seconds. 
    timer1.Elapsed += timer1_Tick;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
```

File Checking:
This is a little harder as the correct way would be to store a hash of the bytes of the file, and to then check if that hash has changed (might be a little too advanced for what you need to do).

So instead, you can create a timer and check to see if the line numbers have changed between file checks. Since this is homework, i'll let you try and we can help you if you run into issues :).

**EDIT:**

You can create a function that passes a button to it to update a specific button:

```
private void ButtonColor (Button ButtonToFlash)
{
  if (ButtonToFlash.BackColor == Color.Gray)
    {
        ButtonToFlash.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        ButtonToFlash.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

Then you would put this in your timer1_Tick:

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonColor(btnTable19); //Or whatever button you want.
}
```

Comment: Ryan, but how to let blinking the specific button (one of 18)? My ideas - create file that name is table number or write table number into file and then somehow read and use it (maybe something with IF?) How to check or file info was changed i know (if (Cont % 2 == 0)
                button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            else
                button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            Cont ++;

Comment: Editing to show how to pass a control.

Comment: but it's no how related to table number, that is random selected and displayed in toolStripStatusLabel

Comment: Well, try it out and update the code. The code I posted is meant to be used as to how to make the button flash once you find out what button it is. I'm not going to do your homework for you, try something and if you can't figure it out, come ask us!

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to write label text to file, but it's writes to file not the random numbert, but text "new Random". What could be the reason? public Random table_nr = new Random();
        public int snr;
        

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("../../../../orders.txt");
            int staliuko_nr = table_nr.Next(1, 18);
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Hi, your table nr.: " + table_nr.ToString();
            
            file.WriteLine("Table nr: " + table_nr);
            file.Close();

Comment: I believe you are wanting to do: `int staliuko_nr = table_nr.Next(1, 18); toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Hi, your table nr.: " + staliuko_nr.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

On my college time we had nearly the same task. There was airport system on “Java”. We used “sever-client” technology with simple communication protocol.

Sure... you can make this task using text file and event handler which checking text file every few seconds/minutes, but this is ugly, unprofessional and useless for real life.

As simple example: no feedback to customers. What it mean – if customer pushed the button, but text file was not changed (network problem, other customer pushed button at the same time, and so on), then customer will never get his order, because waiter have no idea about it.

Comment: true, but still i need to do it..

Comment: Neturiu pakankamai karmos komentuoti, todėl rašau čia. Reikia vietoj: 
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Hi, your table nr.: " + table_nr.ToString(); 

parašyti:

    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Hi, your table nr.: " + staliuko_nr.ToString();